# Select Pandas rows based on list value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like so:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1072 entries, 0 to 1071
Data columns (total 10 columns):
city            1072  non-null values
latitude        1072  non-null values
longitude       1072  non-null values
manufacturer    1072  non-null values
name            1072  non-null values
offering        1072  non-null values
platformID      1072  non-null values
procedure       1072  non-null values
properties      1072  non-null values
sensorID        1072  non-null values
dtypes: object(10)
```

`properties` is a list of string values:

```
df_devices.head(1).properties
Out[79]: 0    [urn:average_wind, urn:dew_point]
```

I'd like to select records that only contain the 'urn:dew_point' entry, but I'm not sure how to filter them (using `isin`, or an alternative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use an [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) to do this:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[['urn:dew_point'], 1]], columns=['properties', 'id'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
        properties  id
0  [urn:dew_point]   1

In [13]: df[df['properties'].apply(lambda x: 'urn:dew_point' in x)]
Out[13]:
        properties  id
0  [urn:dew_point]   1
```

If this were simply part of a string column you could use `str.contains`:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([['urn:dew_point', 1]], columns=['properties', 'id'])

In [22]: df['properties'].str.contains('urn:dew_point')
Out[22]:
0    True
Name: properties, dtype: bool

In [23]: df[df['properties'].str.contains('urn:dew_point')]
Out[23]:
      properties  id
0  urn:dew_point   1
```